# different results for web and desktop applications for same code

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, c#-3.0, wmi

I have the following piece of code.

It is returning different results when running on the same machine in case of web and desktop applications.

Here is my code. Please guide me on what to do regarding this???

```
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

    return (from ManagementObject wmiHD in searcher.Get()
            select wmiHD["SerialNumber"] == null ? "VM HD" : wmiHD["SerialNumber"].ToString()).ToList();
```

Here is a LINQ-free version of the same code

```
    var hdCollection = new List<string>();
    var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

    foreach (ManagementObject wmiHD in searcher.Get())
    {
        // get the hardware serial no.
        if (wmiHD["SerialNumber"] == null)
        {
            hdCollection.Add("VM HD");
        }
        else
        {
            hdCollection.Add(wmiHD["SerialNumber"].ToString());
        }
    }
    return hdCollection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could possibly be caused by two things:

- web server runs with different user account (probably NetworkService)
  http://www.bluevisionsoftware.com/WebSite/TipsAndTricksDetails.aspx?Name=AspNetAccount
- web server runs code without Fulltrust permissions (probably medium trust)
  http://discussion.accuwebhosting.com/iis-web-server/993-how-grant-full-trust-mode-domain-asp-net-2-0-iis-6-0-a.html

Both actions can compromise security, but the first one gives more choices to fix this by setting ACLs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The issue was resolved by changing the account to either `Local Service` or `Local System`. Since, setting the account to `Local System` is considered a risk. I'd set the account to `Local Service` and have given the rights to it on the website folder. Thanks for replying again...

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170(WS.10).aspx
for further details, for those who see this question later...